# Error: [arrayReplace] `arr` must be an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, upload

I get the error to draw, move, resize some rectangles over the image upload in React-shape-editor library. It's said "arr.slice is not a function or its return value is not iterable"

My code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/rectangles-ihsgo

My code will let the user upload image, after upload, there is 2 rectangles display but I can not resize, move or draw other rectangles as well. I think the error is in this function:

```
function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ];
}
```

I have looked at a lot of fixing errors but don't know how to fix them. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole state object to `arrayReplace`, you need to pass just `currentItems.items`

Comment: updated new code but the error message is " arr.slice is not a function"

Comment: did you removed the lines 28 and 31? it's two console.log calls with an object as the first argument instead of an array

Comment: how can I figure out it? could you fix it on the sandbox link so I can easy to follow?